# responsive images without getting scaled

Tags: html, css, responsive, responsive-images

I have one image centered on full browser screen, like below

[image]

I am trying to get image responsive without getting scaled. Means I don't want on responsive, image should be small. I just want on smallest size of browser screen center part of image should seen always. Like that on increasing browser screen size from smaller to big, left and right part of image should seen.

On smaller screen image should be like below, Width of image should not change. Also there should not be horizontal scroll.

[image]

**HTML code**

```
<section id="main">
    <header>
        <span class="avatar"><img src="images/test.jpg" alt="" /></span>
    </header>
</section>
```

**Css code**

```
#main {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 27em;
    padding: 4.5em 3em 3em 3em ;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: default;
    opacity: 0.95;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease, -moz-transform 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease, -webkit-transform 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease, -ms-transform 1s ease;
    transition: opacity 1s ease, transform 1s ease;
}

#main .avatar {
    width: 90%; 
    text-align: center; 
    overflow: hidden;  
}

#main .avatar img {
    position: relative; 
    left: 100%;  
    margin-left: -200%;
}
```

With above `css` I am seeing center part of image but I am getting horizontal scroll.

Anyone please tell me, how I should get responsive image(without horizontal scroll) without getting changed image size on responsive ?

**EDIT**

'test.jpg' is person image, not the background image. Background image is different. Person image should behave like background image like in this case

http://cdn.sixrevisions.com/0431-01_responsive_background_image_demo/responsive-full-background-image-demo.html

Please suggest me how my `css` for 'test.jpg' should be?

Answer (score 0):

Use this css for your background

```
#main{
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

This will not change the size of image and only the possible center part will be visible.

Comment: my background image is different. the person image is 'test.jpg'. I have tried by adding above code but no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden` to `#main`, then the horizontal scroll will not appear, the image will not be scaled on small screens and since you already have `text-align: center` set, just the central part of the image will be visible.

Comment: Did you mean it's not removed on small screen? That's because you have a `min-width` set.. you have to delete that and then the horizontal scroll will disappear on small screens too.

Comment: Kiran please put my css code and check horizontal scroll is removed

Comment: yes, its not removed on smaller screen. I tried by removing `min-width` but its not affecting. :( I feel some big incorrect combination in my css.

Comment: min-width:auto; and also change padding: 4.5em 0 3em; then check.